# Developing a Standalone application with spring framework

Tags: spring, desktop-application

I have a few questions related to developing a standalone application with the spring frawework

- What should the UI preferably be in?
- Any particular scenarios or frameworks like the Spring Rich Client where Spring framework has been used to create a standalone application?

It will be of great help if some link for creating the same can be shared?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- I don't think there is any preference in UI toolkit, but I would use Swing. Simply for the fact that it is built-in to JDK. Obviously SWT can be  used too, but you would have to deploy additional and platform-specific libraries. So in my view using Swing is simply easier (unless you have more experience in SWT)
- Almost any Swing framework can be used with Spring. We used Swing Application Framework, but it really does not matter. Spring Rich Client is outdated though and I wouldn't recommend it.

The most suitable link:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-springswing/

Comment: Would this still be your answer today?

Comment: Today, if you're running on Java 8, I would use JavaFX 8. Of course Swing is still there, but JavaFX is a much more modern toolkit with significant advantages comparing to Swing. It still has some rough edges but is ready for prime time IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to develop my Java portfolio more but there's a pretty broad ecosystem of tools to dig through.